# Can't load the 'rpy2' module after installation in Windows 10

Tags: python, r, package, rpy2

When I try to load through PyCharm some packages in `rpy2` like `importr` with the following code:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
```

I get the following error message

> ValueError: r_home is None. Try python -m rpy2.situation

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have release 2.1.5 and up (they fix issues with [r_home](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/changes.html?highlight=r_home) in it).

If this is not the case, maybe this could help (taken from [here](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/rinterface.html?highlight=r_home)):

> If calling `initr()` returns an error stating that `R_HOME` is not defined, you should either have the R executable in your path (`PATH` on unix-alikes, or `Path` on Microsoft Windows) or have the environment variable `R_HOME` defined. 
>   Should the initialization fail, a mismatch between the version of the R rpy2 was compiled against and the R rpy2 is run with should be investigated. The variable `rpy2.rinterface.R_BUILD_VERSION` contains information about the R version rpy2 was built against. rpy2 is relatively independent of R versions, but changes in the R C API might cause problems.